# What is the best enchantments for Netherite tools?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is the best enchantments for Netherite tools in Minecraft Bedrock? I've looked everywhere and can't find anything. When I do find something the enchantments aren't in order so it's harder to enchant them.

Comment: When you say "best", do you mean the highest tier of each enchantment? If not, this sounds subjective which would be off topic.

Answer (score 4):

This is taken from Minecraft wiki, it's a useful [Summary of enchantments by item](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Summary_of_enchantments_by_item):

[image: Summary of enchantments]